# How to create a limit list of users on Django social login

Tags: django

As the title suggests, how can I create a limit list of users in django social login, so that only authorized users are able to login with their social account?

For example, a user with certain gmail account can login, but others cannot login using unauthorized gmail accounts. Right now, if I use allauth, all users who have gmail account can login to my django site, but that's not what I expect. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by certain Gmail or unauthorized Gmail account

Comment: Hi, that means I don't want all users to login, but only users authorized access by admin can login.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that only emails with existing accounts in your site can login using django-social-auth, then you can update the pipeline of your login. You can find the documentation here: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html.

If you disable the `social_core.pipeline.user.create_user` step of the pipeline, then the social login will only allow login to users which already existed in the site.

Comment: Hi, I am a beginner of django, but I got a direction from your answer. Thanks a lot!